# Can't load models from torchvision on GPU clusters in my company

Tags: docker, pytorch, gpu, cluster-computing, torchvision

codes:

```
from torchvision.models import vgg16
vgg_model = vgg16(pretrained=True).features[:16]
```

the log output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 95, in <module>
    vgg_model = vgg16(pretrained=True).features[:16]
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/models/vgg.py", line 150, in vgg16
    return _vgg('vgg16', 'D', False, pretrained, progress, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/models/vgg.py", line 93, in _vgg
    progress=progress)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/hub.py", line 480, in load_state_dict_from_url
    os.makedirs(model_dir)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 213, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 213, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 223, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.cache'
```

I have to run my codes on GPU clusters, and I have no rights to modify these docker images on GPU clusters. What can I do?

Comment: Seems like you're trying to download weights for VGG but you don't have permissions to save them anywhere

Comment: Can you download weights locally e.g. from Kaggle and put them on the docker image? You can easily load it with `vgg_model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))`